# Google Maps API displaying grey screen

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have been struggling to fix this issue, but nothing I have found online has worked. I have gotten an unrestricted key for my project, but the map will still not display correctly. The status that is returned is considered OK, but nothing displays. I have also made sure to enable both APIs for that key. Below are some pictures showing what it looks like followed by my code. If I need to include any other code just comment on what you need. I'm also using the Google Direction Library found here https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionLibrary

[image: Before Click]

[image: After Click]

After the button is clicked, it goes to the correct area, but everything is grey so I believe there is a problem with my google maps.

Dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.akexorcist:googledirectionlibrary:1.0.5'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

XML Fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_directions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="<did not show my package>.Directions">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="<did not show my package>.MapsActivity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/get_directions_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Get Directions" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Directions.java

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.akexorcist.googledirection.DirectionCallback;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.GoogleDirection;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.constant.TransportMode;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.model.Direction;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.model.Route;
import com.akexorcist.googledirection.util.DirectionConverter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Directions extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
                                View.OnClickListener, DirectionCallback
{
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private LatLng origin = new LatLng(29.572813, -97.984900);
    private LatLng destination;
    private Button get_directions_btn;
    private String serverKey = "<server key not shown>";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_directions);


        // origin = new LatLng(29.572813, -97.984900);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        double destLatitude = bundle.getDouble("latitude");
        double destLongitude = bundle.getDouble("longitude");
        Log.d("Latitude", "Latitude is: " + destLatitude);
        Log.d("Longitude", "Longitude is:" + destLongitude);
        destination = new LatLng(destLatitude, destLongitude);

        get_directions_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_directions_btn);
        get_directions_btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment)).getMapAsync(this);
    }

    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.googleMap = googleMap;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();
        if (id == R.id.get_directions_btn) {
            requestDirection();

        }
    }

    public void requestDirection() {
        Log.d("RequestOrigin", "Origin inside request: " + origin);
        Log.d("RequestDestination", "Destination inside request: " + destination);
        Snackbar.make(get_directions_btn, "Direction Requesting...", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GoogleDirection.withServerKey(serverKey)
                .from(origin)
                .to(destination)
                .transportMode(TransportMode.DRIVING)
                .execute(this);
    }

    public void onDirectionSuccess(Direction direction, String rawBody) {
        Log.d("Status","Direction Status is:" +direction.getStatus());
        Snackbar.make(get_directions_btn, "Success with status : " + direction.getStatus(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (direction.isOK()) {
            Route route = direction.getRouteList().get(0);
            Log.d("Route ", "Route is: " + route);

            Log.d("Origin Marker", "Origin Marker: " + origin);
            Log.d("Destination Marker", "Destination Marker: " + destination);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(origin));
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(destination));

            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = route.getLegList().get(0).getDirectionPoint();
            googleMap.addPolyline(DirectionConverter.createPolyline(this, directionPositionList, 5, Color.RED));
            setCameraWithCoordinationBounds(route);

            get_directions_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        else{
            Log.d("Status","Direction Status is:" +direction.getStatus());
            Snackbar.make(get_directions_btn, direction.getStatus(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

        public void onDirectionFailure(Throwable t) {
            Snackbar.make(get_directions_btn, t.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    private void setCameraWithCoordinationBounds(Route route) {
        LatLng southwest = route.getBound().getSouthwestCoordination().getCoordination();
        LatLng northeast = route.getBound().getNortheastCoordination().getCoordination();
        LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast);
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100));
    }
}
```

Manifest meta data

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

Manifest Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you can try to apply [custom style to Google Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling). For map style JSON preparing you can use [Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/) and save JSON file with style description (e.g. `map_style.json`) into `res/raw` folder. And than apply custom style in `onMapReady()` callback:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MapFragment mapFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        try {
            // Customise the styling of the base map using a JSON object defined
            // in a raw resource file.
            boolean success = mGoogleMap.setMapStyle(
                    MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(
                            this, R.raw.map_style));

            if (!success) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Can't find style. Error: ", e);
        }


    }

}
```